# crystal reports - summarizing/grouping/associating data

Tags: crystal-reports

I a trying to sort this data in a usable single page report by Person and this is what I have.  Am new to crystal reports.  I am trying to get a list of a patient, their problems and medicines on one page (there can be multiple Problems and Medicines under 1 Patient).  Data is coming from three different tables linked by patient, I am wanting to group all of the problems together and group all of the medicines together like this....

```
Group #1   Patient: John Doe

Group #2   Problem:  Hypertension            
           Problem:  Headaches
           Problem:  GERD

Group #3   Medicines:  Prilosec
           Medicines:  Imitrex
           Medicines:  Zestril
```

I am getting this

```
Group #1   Patient: John Doe

Group #2   Problem:  Hypertension   
                         Medicines:  Prilosec
                         Medicines:  Imitrex
                         Medicines:  Zestril         
           Problem:  Headaches
                         Medicines:  Prilosec
                         Medicines:  Imitrex
                         Medicines:  Zestril
           Problem:  GERD
                         Medicines:  Prilosec
                         Medicines:  Imitrex
                         Medicines:  Zestril
```

Comment: Not enough information to really debug this. It looks like you may have to create another group to get what you want. Because crystal reports are somewhat binary and not text it is almost impossible to "post your code".

Comment: What have you tried? what sources have you looked to for answers? how are your reports set up? how are your tables linked? My point is that you haven't provided enough information to help you. It sounds like you have a fairly easy problem, but your question is too vague at this point. please visit this link for clarification http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question is much clearer now. Good job. It looks like aMazing's answer should get you the results you want.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible and I think your requirement is quite clear, just that you havent given details about your environment. Anyway, 
Try this solution:

```
1) Create Group1-A - Patient 
   a) Insert a Subreport on this section
   b) On the subreport link it such that Patients <-> Problems field
   c) Add relevant Problem fields
2) Create Group1-B - Patient 
   a) Insert another Subreport on this section
   b) On the subreport link it such that Patients <-> Medicines field
   c) Add relevant Medicine fields
```

Let me know how that goes and if that does the job, if not get back with you what it does and we can go from there.